# Assigning static IP to wlan0 for AP

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have a Raspberry Pi and am following this guide to configure it as a a routed AP:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Previously I had no problems using the wlan0 interface to connect to my ISP AP and assigning it a static IP. Now that I am trying to assign it an IP without first being connected to an AP, it seems to be a problem.

I've added this to mt /etc/dhcpcd.conf file:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

But when I restart dhcpcd, there is no IP assigned to wlan0:

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether dc:a6:32:da:13:e8 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 921 bytes 90872 (88.7 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1620 bytes 197769 (193.1 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

The logs shows these lines:

```
Nov 18 20:14:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[7779]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.4.0/24
Nov 18 20:14:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[7779]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.4.1
Nov 18 20:14:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[7779]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.4.1/24
Nov 18 20:14:47 raspberrypi dhcpcd[7779]: wlan0: removing interface
Nov 18 20:14:47 raspberrypi dhcpcd[7779]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::dea6:32ff:feda:13e8

Nov 18 20:14:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[8423]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Nov 18 20:14:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[8423]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: Please add formatting and a complete URL!

Comment: I do not agree very much with the tutorial you have used. They are mixing up traditional networking with systemd. You may try to use a clean systemd-networkd solution with [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).